# Raising a Set to another Set Discrete Mathematics

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am having a little trouble this problem. Namely (3). Any insights would be appreciated.

Let $A = \{x \in \mathbb{R} | -3 \leq x \leq 0 \}$, $B = \{x \in \mathbb{R} | -1 < x < 2\}$, $C = \{x \in \mathbb{R} |7 < x \leq 9 \}$. Find the following:

(1) $A \cup B$
(2) $A \cap B$
(3) $A^C$
(4) $A \cap C$

Comment: While this may be an exercise in your discrete maths class, the problem itself belongs to the mathematical field of set theory, so I edited the tag. You can look at the tag description for ```discrete-mathematics``` to see it doesn't match your question.

Comment: In set theory we have: for sets $A,B$ the expression $A^B$ usually denotes the set of all functions form $B$ to $A$ -- but I'd eat a hat if that's what the questions asks for here. It most certainly refers to the complement.

Comment: Since its stated that the universal set is R, all real numbers, I'm assuming A^C would then be all reals not on the domain [-3,0]?

Answer (score 2):

That "c" in the exponent means [*complement*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)), which is all the elements *not* in set A. It has nothing to do with set C.

Comment: Nope, I've looked through the book as well and there is no mention of it.

Answer (score 0):

As someone else stated, it's just the complement. If you've seen the notation with a line over the set, you can just commit to memory that for a set, $A$ the following is true: $$A^C = \overline{A}$$